# Converting a string to Cardinal / UInt32

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, delphi-xe7

I need to convert a string to an unsigned 32 bit integer ([`Cardinal`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Cardinal)).

In `System.SysUtils` unit there are many useful functions like:

- `StrToInt`
- `StrToInt64`
- `StrToUInt64`

But I can't find any `StrToCardinal`, `StrToUInt` or `StrToUInt32` function.

Comment: [`StrToUInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.StrToUInt)?

Comment: Why do you need one? Why isn't `:= StrToInt()` enough for you? Have you encountered an actual problem? There also exists no `StrToWord()` and `StrToByte()`...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I can't find it in my `System.SysUtils` (DelphiXE7), how is it implemented?

Comment: @AmigoJack: I know, but I have to work with `Cardinal` values (i.e: PIDs)

Comment: @Fabrizio: I suspected that. It merely converts the string to a 64-bit integer, checks if it is within a cardinal's range, and if so casts and if not raises an exception. It's a trivial three-liner.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Ok, thanks I'll do the same in my function

Comment: @DelphiCoder: As far as I know, the compiler looks at the parameters in order to distinguish between all the available overloads of a given method. In this case I would always pass a string as parameter, for this reason there are different named methods for each type (i.e: `StrToInt` and `StrToInt64`). Anyhow, if I call `StrToInt64` it works but I will have troubles if the passed value is out of the `Cardinal`'s range, so the solution is to call `StrToInt64` and checking if the resulting `Int64` value is in the `Cardinal`'s range (as Andreas said in his previous comment)

Comment: @DelphiCoder: You cannot overload with different result types only.

Comment: Forget my comment, I confused ``IntToStr`` with ``StrToInt``!

Comment: Wanting to know what unit to include to uses to do cardinal.tostring helpers.

Searching for "delphi cardinal variable .tostring helper unit generics" gives no usable search results. Indication of the sad fragmented state of the documentation for this great language/tool.

Faster to get full uses list from one's other project and comment them out one at a time until you identify which unit is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow Andreas Rejbrand idea posted as comment, I would suggest this:

```
function StrToCardinal(const S : String) : Cardinal;
var
    I64 : UInt64;
begin
    I64 := StrToUInt64(S);
    if (I64 shr 32) <> 0 then
        raise EConvertError.Create('StrToCardinal invalid value');
    Result := Cardinal(I64);
end;
```

Comment: @AmigoJack: The OP said in the Q that `StrToUInt64` exists. It's the third bullet in the list.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.StrToUInt64

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am afraid I don't quite see what you mean by giving that link. The OP already said that the function exists in XE7 and a link to the Sydney docs doesn't say much about the situation in XE7. Perhaps you meant to (1) give the link http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.StrToUInt64 and (2) address the comment to AmigoJack?

Comment: @AmigoJack I tested my code with D10.4.1 and the OP said StrToUInt64 already existed at XE7 time.